# Xamarin Forms Error Handling - Message Center Alert not displaying from Data Store

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224487/xamarin-forms-error-handling-messaging-center-alert-not-displaying-from-model) post on messaging center. I wanted to use this method to display errors when I encounter them in my Data Store classes (please let me know if this is not kosher). However, it is not working.

Login Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginDataStore, MessagingCenterAlert>(this, "message", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("UH OH!", arg.Message, "OK");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

LoginDataStore.cs

```
public class LoginDataStore
{
    HttpClient client;

    public LoginDataStore()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{App.BackendUrl}/");
    }

    public async void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        });

        try
        {
            var result = await client.PostAsync("/oauth/token", content);

            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception(result.StatusCode.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Please check your email and password.");

            dynamic resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultContent);

            Settings.AuthToken = (string)resultObject["access_token"].Value;

            Settings.UserId = username;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // remove later when the messaging center works 
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed!", e.Message, "OK");

            MessagingCenter.Send(new MessagingCenterAlert
            {
                Title = "Login Failed",
                Message = e.Message,
                Cancel = "OK"
            }, e.Message);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, with breakpoints, I can see that the Message is getting created and the Login Page is subscribed, but the code inside the subscription never gets called and no message appears. The brute force code of direct calling the page works, but it's not exactly elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Your subscriber is not listening for the same `message` key that the sender is sending.  They need to match, like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginDataStore, MessagingCenterAlert> (this, "LoginFailureMessage", (sender, args) => {
    // do something whenever the "LoginFailureMessage" message is sent
});

MessagingCenter.Send<LoginDataStore, MessagingCenterAlert> (this, "LoginFailureMessage", new MessagingCenterAlert
        {
            Title = "Login Failed",
            Message = e.Message,
            Cancel = "OK"
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I just could not see it!